# Spark dataframe aggregate on multiple columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
Actually I am working on pyspark code. My dataframe is

+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|element|collect1|collect2|collect3|collect4|
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|A1     |   1.02 |    2.6 |   5.21 |    3.6 |
|A2     |   1.61 |   2.42 |   4.88 |   6.08 |
|B1     |   1.66 |   2.01 |    5.0 |    4.3 |
|C2     |   2.01 |   1.85 |   3.42 |   4.44 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need to find the mean and stddev for each element by aggregating all the collectX columns. The final result should be as below.

```
+-------+--------+--------+
|element|mean    |stddev  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|A1     |   3.11 |   1.76 |
|A2     |   3.75 |   2.09 |
|B1     |   3.24 |   1.66 |
|C2     |   2.93 |   1.23 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

The below code breakdown all the mean at individual columns
df.groupBy("element").mean().show(). Instead of doing for each column, is it possible to rollup for all the columns?

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|element|avg(collect1)|avg(collect2)|avg(collect3)|avg(collect4)|
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|A1     |   1.02      |   2.6       |   5.21      |    3.6      |
|A2     |   1.61      |   2.42      |   4.88      |   6.08      |
|B1     |   1.66      |   2.01      |    5.0      |    4.3      |
|C2     |   2.01      |   1.85      |   3.42      |   4.44      |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I tried to make use of the describe function as it has the complete aggregation functions but still shown as individual column
df.groupBy("element").mean().describe().show()

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spark allows you to gather all sort of stats per column. You are trying to calculate stats per row. In this case you can hack something with `udf`. Here is an example :D

```
$ pyspark
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import array, udf
>>>
>>> mean = udf(lambda v: sum(v) / len(v), DoubleType())
>>> df = sc.parallelize([['A1', 1.02, 2.6, 5.21, 3.6], ['A2', 1.61, 2.42, 4.88, 6.08]]).toDF(['element', 'collect1', 'collect2', 'collect3', 'collect4'])
>>> df.show()
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|element|collect1|collect2|collect3|collect4|
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     A1|    1.02|     2.6|    5.21|     3.6|
|     A2|    1.61|    2.42|    4.88|    6.08|
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
>>> df.select('element', mean(array(df.columns[1:])).alias('mean')).show()
+-------+------+
|element|  mean|
+-------+------+
|     A1|3.1075|
|     A2|3.7475|
+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just adding the columns together and possibly dividing by 4?

```
SELECT avg((collect1 + collect2 + collect3 + collect4) / 4),
  stddev((collect1 + collect2 + collect3 + collect4) / 4)
```

That's not going to do exactly what you want but get the idea.

Not sure your language, but you can always build the query on the fly if you aren't happy with hardcoded:

```
val collectColumns = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("collect"))
val stmnt = "SELECT avg((" + collectColumns.mkString(" + ") + ") / " + collectColumns.length + "))"
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Actually, the dataframe may have more or less of collectX columns. Doing hardcoded is not the preferred choice.